If condition fails and does not go in else block as using 'contains'
In the Material UI table there is one record which can exist or not.
The scenario is if that row is present based on 'Name' column then delete it, otherwise go to the else block and log that record is not present.
In my code if the row is present then it executes the if block and the rest is fine.
But when the row doesn't exist then it is not going to the else block.
cy.get('.MuiTable-root').first().contains(Program1).then(($el) => {

  if ($el.length > 0) {
    // Element exists, do something
    cy.log(Program1 + ': Program found.')
    cy.get('.MuiTable-root').first().contains('tr', Program1).find('td').first().find('svg.MuiSvgIcon-root').eq(2).click();
    cy.wait(10000)
    cy.get('[title="Save"]').click()
    cy.wait(10000)
    cy.log( Program1 + ': Program deleted.')
  } else {
    // Element does not exist, do something else
    console.log(Program1 + ': Program not found.');
    cy.wait(3000)
    cy.log( Program1 + ': Program not found.')
  }
  cy.wait(5000)
  cy.get('.lw-header__logout > img').click();
  cy.wait(5000)
})

I'm getting error when executing the code, saying that the row doesn't exist.


You do not need to wait 30 seconds for this test to run, instead add timeouts to queries.

It would be possible if you move the conditional portion of the query inside the .then() callback, and check it synchronously.
So instead of this
cy.get('.MuiTable-root').first().contains(Program1).then(($el) => {
  if ($el.length > 0) {
    ...

you would do this (simplest version)
cy.get('.MuiTable-root').first().then($table => {
  const hasRequiredText = $table.text().includes(Program1) 
  if (hasRequiredText ) {
    ...

This would be sufficient for a static table (already loaded).
In case the table data comes from an API call, you need to wait for the rows to be loaded before you can correctly check.
Adding additional safe-guards such as asserting the row count will retry until the rows are loaded.
cy.get('.MuiTable-root').first()
  .find('tbody tr')
  .should('not.have.length', 0)     // better than cy.wait(10_000)
  .then($rows => {
    const hasRequiredText = [...$rows].some(row => {
      return row.innerText.includes(Program1) 
    })
    if (hasRequiredText ) {
      ...


you cannot base conditional logic on the returned value of cy.contains() as it will fail if passed string is not located within the DOM. 
My advice would be to base conditional logic on data received from the server. If you are not using some static content, but receive it from somewhere you can use cy.intercept() and base the logic on what you get from a response. You can interact with the response via response properties. 
If this is not based on some sort of server data though, you should probably have some control over test data, and in this case simply have two separate cases - one for record deletion, and other for record creation. Conditional logic in tests is an anti-pattern in general.
